# uiimage simulator image won't scale

Tags: ios, swift, image, ios-simulator, xcode7

I'm trying to insert the image into the image view using tap gesture. And it works like this:[image]

But when I'm trying to use stack layout I get this problem: [image]

In attribute inspector I have tried using "scale to fill" , "aspect fill" and "aspect fit" but it didn't help me. Also, I have noticed that when I'm trying to set any type of constraint to image this resize problem happens.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you resize you `UIImageView`?

Comment: update your code too

Comment: @Artem Novichkov. I've just tried to use stack layout for text field and image view.

Comment: What's frame of your `UIImageView` after set image action?

Comment: @Artem Novichkov. Frame rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Set top, bottom, left and right constraints for stack view. Use "aspect fit" content mode for `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

After a while I managed to solve this issue. The solution came out by itself when I updated my Xcode to 8.2 (Swift 3). For me the scaling problem goes away when in attribute inspector for imageview I declare "intrinsic size" to be placeholder. After that using "pin menu" I select aspect ratio and define constraints and that's it. Hope it helps for someone.